# Add 30 minutes to time in calendar event in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I am trying to add events created in my Flutter app to a Google calendar. It requires a startTime and endTime.

I can set the startTime from a DatePicker but I want to add a 30 minute duration for the event. What I am trying is not working.

```
DateTime endTime =
   ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider).eventDate!;
   endTime.add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(eventDurationController.text)));
```

I get the duration (in minutes) from a Textfield widget so I need to parse it to get the value. I have tried to just hardcode the value but it still doesn't update the value of minutes.

Here is what is contained in the endTime variable before I try to add 30 minutes:

```
__parts:
List (9 items)
_value:
1703715840000000
day:27
hashCode:23672341
hour:15
isUtc:false
microsecond:0
microsecondsSinceEpoch:1703715840000000
millisecond:0
millisecondsSinceEpoch:1703715840000
minute:24
month:12
runtimeType:
Type (DateTime)
second:0
timeZoneName:"MST"
timeZoneOffset:
Duration (-7:00:00.000000)
weekday:3
year:2023
```

So, I start out with hours: 15 and minutes 24  and when I add 30 nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`add`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) method does not modify the object, but rather creates a new instance with the added duration. So you need to reassign the variable:

```dart
endTime = endTime.add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(eventDurationController.text)));
```

You can also use it directly at the declaration:

```dart
DateTime endTime =
   ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider).eventDate!
    .add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(eventDurationController.text)));
```